# How to resolve the error "'nc' not available in my environment."

Tags: bash, netcat

I try to run this command to validate if zookeeper service is healthy or not
`echo ruok | nc localhost 2181`

and i got this error in the terminal 'nc' not available in my environment.

what is the solution for this error?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have **anything** to do with PostScript so I'm removing the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command to connect zookeeper

```
telnet localhost 2181
```

Then if you connected you can
type `ruok` and press Enter.
Check the response you receive. If ZooKeeper is healthy, it should respond with `imok`.

Comment: Ideally, you'd use `zookeeper-shell`, or `zkCli` instead